# How to select rows in pandas based on list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find out a way how I can select rows in pandas dataframe based that some values will be in my list. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2), columns=['A','B'])
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
```

I know that I can select certain row, e.g.

```
df[df.A==0]
```

will select me row with A=0. What I want is to select multiple rows whose values will be in my list, e.g. A in [0,2]. I tried

```
df[df.A in [0,2]]
df[list(df.A)==[0,2]]
```

but nothing works. In R language I can provide %in% operator. In python syntax we can use A in [0,2], etc. How I can select subset of rows in pandas in this case?
Thanks,
Valentin.

Answer (score 30):

pd.isin() will select multiple values:

```
>>> df[df.A.isin([0,2])]
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
```

Comment: Brian, thanks that works. How about negation operation, i.e, not in?

Comment: You can use numpy's logical_not: df[np.logical_not(df.A.isin([0,2]))]

Comment: Great, that's answer completely my question.

Comment: Is there a way to use pandas df.loc , iloc or ix to do this?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you are 'cheating' by knowing the which rows you are looking for. (In this example, df.iloc[0:2] (1st and 2nd rows) and df.loc[0:1] (rows with index value in the range of 0-1 (the index being unlabeled column on the left) both give you the equivalent output, but you had to know in advance. If you want a different syntax, there is a df.query() method.

Comment: Apparently `df[~df['A'].isin([0, 2])]` is another way of negating it.

Comment: This last solution from @John is not working for me.

Comment: Seems to work for me still.  Using the OP's dataframe, `df[~df['A'].isin([0, 2])]` returns the correct answer, i.e., row 2:  (4, 5).

Answer (score 3):

if you don't like that syntax, you can use also use [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/indexing.html#indexing-query) (introduced in pandas 0.13 which is from 2014):

```
>>> df.query('A in [0,2]')
   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
```